# Winter refers to what climate

Tags: matthew, bible-versions

I believe the Bible mentions "winter" a total of [16 times](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=winter&qs_version=NIV).  (I am hopeful the following is an appropriate question)

For example **Matthew 24:20**

```
Pray that your flight will not take place in winter or on the Sabbath.
```

When the bible refers to winter in the 17 different verse what type of climate is it referring to?  Most specifically does "winter" mean the same thing for all the 16 verses, or is there any specific way to tell?

[Climate Map Full image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ifOwcB6YX5E/UY5sP2AgYLI/AAAAAAAAAbQ/bTixtKgYxJ4/s1600/climate_map.gif)

More importantly how much snow fall are we dealing with or was there not any snow in the demographics/time the bible was written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Winter refers to what climate

According to [ISBE](http://www.studylight.org/enc/isb/view.cgi?n=9124&search=Winter#Winter), Winter is the "rainy season." The rainy season ushers in a marked change in temperature from highs during the summer ranging from 85°F to triple digits. The "winter" months have both hard frosts and snow each year.

Apparently the biblical writers were not focused as much on "seasons" as they were on times when various events were taking place; planting, harvest, rain, drought, etc.

Two words stand out with regard to "times/seasons," namely, môʿēḏ (from which come the "appointed times") and ʿēṯ. These words stand out in passages such as:

- [Leviticus 26:4](http://biblia.com/books/kjv/Le26.4)
- [Ecclesiastes 3:1](http://biblia.com/books/kjv/Ec3.1)
- [Daniel 2:21](http://biblia.com/books/kjv/Da2.21)

> For more on this, especially seasons/times, see ISBE Volume 4, page
>   375

Comment: What is ISBE? Surely it isn't Illinois State Board of Education which is the top Google result? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Cohen_the_Librarian So sorry. International Standard Bible Encyclopedia.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your post is by editing it, with the **edit** button. It is more visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your post should be in the post itself.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how much snow/frost would you guess?

Comment: @LiamWilliam Snowfall would be less than one inch annually (on average), although Jerusalem received approximately 12 inches of snow on December 13, 2013.

Answer (score 2):

In Aramaic of Peshitta this word for winter is ܒܣܬܘܐ and it can also (apart from *winter*) mean *tempest*, *foul weather*, *stormy weather* (according to *Lexicon to the Syriac New Testament* by William Jennings and J. Payne Smith's *A Compendious Syriac Dictionary*). You could think about interpreting Matthew 24:20 as referring to a stormy weather.